# How to present predicted probabilities for multiple predictors

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, data-visualization

I have performed a multinomial logistic regression using the multinom function in R. I have one categorical response variable with 3 levels, 3 continuous predictors and 3 categorical predictors (with 3, 4 and 5 levels). I thought about plotting the predicted probabilities in a facet style plot until I quickly realised that with this many variables it's not really possible to do that two-dimensionally.

Any suggestions for how to present predicted probabilities when you have multiple predictors (some continuous, some categorical), like this?

Comment: Can you provide some kind of reproducible example for people to work with? Are there any interactions in your model? What do you want to show & why, ie, what is the goal of the visualization?